# Signed Encrypted Message Java BouncyCastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I'm using Java 1.6 and the libraries of Bouncy Castle bcmail-jdk-15-140.jar and bcprov-jdk15-140.jar.
I created an encrypted and signed message  but when the sign should be checked, exception is thrown.
Specifically, the signature of my message was created in this way;

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); 
byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(senderKeyStoreFileLocation); 
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12","BC"); 
ks.load(fis, keyStorePass);      

PrivateKey pKey = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(senderAlias, keyStorePass); 
X509Certificate  cert = (X509Certificate)ks.getCertificate(senderAlias);

CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator(); 

gen.addSigner(pKey, cert, CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1);

Certificate[] certChain = ks.getCertificateChain(senderAlias); 
CertStore certs = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", new CollectionCertStoreParameters(Arrays.asList(certChain)), "BC");

gen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certs);
CMSProcessable content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(bytes);

CMSSignedData s = gen.generate(CMSSignedDataGenerator.DATA,content,false,"BC",true);

byte[] b = toDERObject(s.getEncoded()).getDEREncoded();
String sign = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(b, true));
```

The verification is as follow:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "BC");

ks.load(new FileInputStream(recipientKeyStoreFileLocation), keyStorePass);
EncryptionUtils cryptoUtils = EncryptionManager.getEncryptionUtils(EncryptionManager.SMIME);

Boolean verified = Boolean.FALSE;
Certificate senderCert = ks.getCertificate(recipientAlias);

MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(encryptedSignedMsg);
Boolean verified = cryptoUtils.checkSignature(m, senderCert.getPublicKey());
```

The exception is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: 
invalid signature format in message: content hash found in signed attributes different
at net.suberic.crypto.bouncycastle.SMIMEEncryptionUtils.checkSignature(SMIMEEncryptionUtils.java:383)
at net.suberic.crypto.bouncycastle.SMIMEEncryptionUtils.checkSignature(SMIMEEncryptionUtils.java:320)
```

I can’t figure out how to fix it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: no answer? I have the same issue :(